# External access to Magento instances

Tags: zend-framework, magento-1.7, magento

I've started investigating alternatives to my project and a few questions came out that I couldn't answer by myself.

The problem is: I want to create a web page able to access multiple Magento instances installed in the same server. Currently, I have one Magento instance per client and this project will access several Magneto instances to export reports from each one (for example).

The alternatives I thought til this moment are:

- Have another Magento instance, create a new module within it that changes its 'database target' before triggering operations/queries;

Questions until this moment:

- **Can I 'change the database target' of a Magento instance?**
- **How can I access data from a Magento instance without appeal to SOAP/REST?**
- I want to re-use some components (grids, tabs, forms..) from Magento, that's why I'm not considering an independent project (Zend, for instance) that can access this code from another projects. Does it make sense?
- Any other idea?

**==Edited==**

Thanks by the tips and sorry by my ignorance. The comments let me believe that I'm able to execute something like this:

```
// File myScript.php
require '/home/DOMAIN1/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
// get some products from DOMAIN1

require '/home/DOMAIN2/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
// get some products from DOMAIN2
```

Is it right? Can I execute require twice (and override things from first require)?

**==Edited2==**

I'm still trying to connect to several Magento instances from a single third party file. Is there any tip? I'm facing several/different errors at this moment.

The only thing I know is that I can still rely on SOAP to get the information I need, but this will be expensive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to include Mage.php from each shop instance. You would need to use namespaces or some other trickery to be able to load more then one.

Or if that doesn't work - make your own API in a separate file to get what you want from one shop, and combine the results in the PHP-file that calls the API.

Here's a sample on how to use Magento functionality outside of Magento:

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// your custom code here, for example, get the product model..
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

Comment: I've tried the namespace approach but it messed out with the Magento. Do you have any tip/tutorial to proceed with this approach? Also, I didn't get your second approach (what you calling API?). Thanks a lot!